# how to enable "Default Address" on cPanel, I can't see the icon there

Tags: php, ssh, centos, cpanel, whm

I've purchased a new VPS from Bluehost and I got the server with CentOS installed and cPanel on it, on my other server, I had an icon under the "email" tab on cPanel called "Default Address", over there i could set up to pipe all unattended email addresses to a php script, Now on my new server I simply don't see that option.

Is there any way to add/enable this option from the WHM interface or to do something else like login to my root with SSH and change something?

Or , is there any other option to accomplish what I'm looking for?
I have more than 50 companies registered on my website and each one of theme got an email address with my domain extension. when i get the email to my php script i can read it and know who sent it and update the database with the information they sent over to me. so that's what I'm trying to do here but I have no idea how to get it done without that option on my cPanel.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue, 
if someone will ever get stuck with this problem just go to your

WHM > Feature Manager

list to see if Default Address Manager is checked

and that should solve it.